# remove all the borders from bootstrap table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML**

```
<table class="table " >
    <thead >
        <tr>

            <th>
                Product
            </th>
            <th>
                Price
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr>
            <td  >
                torch   
            </td>
            <td>

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amountC" name="amountC" autocomplete='off' style="outline: none;
                       border:none !important;
                       box-shadow:none !important;">
            </td>


        </tr>


    </tbody>
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>
                <input type="text" style="float:left" name="" id="couo" placeholder="hi" class="form-control" />

            </th>
            <th>
    <div>
        <input type="button" style="padding:5px 12px" name="btnC" id="btnC" class='btn btn-info' value="coupon" />

    </div>
</th>

</tr>

<tr>

    <th>
        Amount to be paid 
    </th>
    <th>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amountT" name="amountT" autocomplete='off' style="outline: none;
               border:none !important;
               box-shadow:none !important;">                                </th>

</tr>
</thead>

</table>
```

I have this HTML in which there are borders in this table.I want to completely remove all the borders inside the table.I tried editing the css.But I cant do that..

here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fethrsupport/Gz49L/1/)

Comment: How do you mean "can't edit the CSS"? Please show us what you've already tried...

Comment: why don't you override the css classes?

Comment: I have given the CSS in the fiddle @BenM  You can check that

Comment: @user3155047 I can only see Bootstrap CSS in there. Where's your custom code you tried?

Comment: I have made changes in that.But didnt work out.

Comment: i tried border:none css for td and table,but still the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did u tried this

```
  <style>
    .table>thead>tr>th, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>td {
border: none!important;
}
    </style>
```

this must help you
check this http://jsfiddle.net/spk063/Gz49L/4/